# DbUpdateException with entities that do not expose foreign key properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I have an entity model with `User` and `Person` entities, such that each `User` must be associated with exactly 1 `Person`, and each `Person` can be associated zero or 1 `User`.

```
User (0..1) <-------> (1) Person
```

The association is mapped fluently. Originally I only had it declared on the `Person` side:

```
private class PersonOrm : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    internal PersonOrm()
    {
        ToTable(typeof(Person).Name, DbSchemaName.People);

        // has zero or one User
        HasOptional(p => p.User)
            .WithRequired(d => d.Person)
            .Map(d => d.MapKey("PersonId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
        ;
```

Since I encountered this error, I also added the same mapping to the `User` side:

```
private class UserOrm : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    internal UserOrm()
    {
        ToTable(typeof(User).Name, DbSchemaName.Identity);

        // has exactly 1 Person
        HasRequired(p => p.Person)
            .WithOptional(d => d.User)
            .Map(d => d.MapKey("PersonId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

There is a scenario in the application where a new `User` can be created and associated with an existing `Person`. This is where I am having difficulty at the moment. EF is considering `User` as the dependent side of the relationship, and is putting a `PersonId (FK, int, not null)` column on the `User` table. I don't believe it's possible to use a foreign key property on either entity to help EF manage the association (is it?).

Here is some failing code that tries to handle the scenario:

```
// find out if Person already exists
var person = context.People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Emails.Any(
    e => e.Value.Equals(emailAddress, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

// find out if User already exists
var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(
    u => u.Name.Equals(emailAddress, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

if (user == null)
{
    user = new User
    {
        Name = emailAddress,
        IsRegistered = isRegistered,
        Person = person ?? PersonFactory.Create(emailAddress),
        // ignore the PersonFactory.Create, that part works
    };

    context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code works fine when `person` is null (does not already exist in the db). However when `person` is not null (already exists in db) and `user` is null, the code attempts to create a new `User` and associate it with the existing `Person`. When invoking `SaveChanges()`, I get a `DbUpdateException`:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

The inner exception is:

> A relationship from the 'User_Person' AssociationSet is in the
>   'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding
>   'User_Person_Source' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

This doesn't make any sense to me because I'm not trying to delete anything, and checking the `EntityState` of both `User` and `Person` shows that `User` is in the `Added` state, whereas `Person` is in the `Unchanged` state. I have overridden `SaveChanges()` to demonstrate:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var userChanges = ChangeTracker.Entries<User>().Single();
    var personChanges = ChangeTracker.Entries<Person>().Single();

    if (userChanges.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("wtf?");

    if (personChanges.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("wtf?");

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

When this code executes, neither `InvalidOperationException` is thrown. Again, `userChanges` is in the `Added` state, and `personChanges` is in the `Unchanged` state.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel really dumb right now. After writing up this careful question, it's now obvious.

The `Person` I am testing with already exists, and already has a `User` association with a different `User.Name`. This is why `user` is coming up null. Setting the `Person.User` property to a new `User` is causing the old `User` to be put in the `Deleted` state. Doh.

Sorry to have wasted your time. I'll leave the question up unless it's agreed it would be better to delete it.

Comment: So how do you get round this? I have a similar problem with a topic that has a last post association. If set the last post to a different post, it tries to delete the previous one!! WTF is that about?

Comment: It is *about* time to switch ORM's from EF to NHibernate! J/K... In my case it was because of the multiplicity constraints. Each User **MUST HAVE** a Person, but a Person can have a null User. When I set Person.User to null, EF first checks the constraints to see whether the other side of the relationship (User.Person) can be set to null. Since it cannot, EF puts User in the deleted state. Had I set the User.Person to null, Person would **not** have been put into the deleted state, since it can have 0..1 User. If your constraints are different, post up a question and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the relationship defined in your mapping (Entity Type Configuration)

For example:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.QuoteResponse).WithMany(t => t.QuoteResponseItems).HasForeignKey(d => d.QuoteResponseID);
```