# Relationship Many to Many Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have classes..

CONSUL_CA_Aluno:

```
public class CONSUL_CA_Aluno
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Cpf { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public int Ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CONSUL_CA_Curso> CONSUL_CA_Cursos { get; set; }
}
```

CONSUL_CA_Curso:

```
public class CONSUL_CA_Curso
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Ativo { get; set; }
    public string Ministrante { get; set; }
    public string Duracao { get; set; }
    public int CargaHoraria { get; set; }
    public string LocalCurso { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CONSUL_CA_Aluno> CONSUL_CA_Alunos { get; set; }
}
```

In bd I have the table CONSUL_CA_CursoAluno.

But, when I test:

```
CONSUL_CA_Aluno aluno = new CONSUL_CA_Aluno();
aluno.Ativo = 1;
aluno.Cpf = 1321;
aluno.Email = "email";
aluno.Nome = "diididid";
aluno.Senha = "123";
aluno.CONSUL_CA_Cursos = contexto.Cursos.ToList();
aluno.CONSUL_CA_Cursos = aluno.CONSUL_CA_Cursos.Select(curso => contexto.Curso.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == curso.Id)).ToList();
contexto.Aluno.Add(aluno);
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Show the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>   Additional information: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Comment: This question has been answered before in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342908/entity-framework-many-to-many-mapping

Comment: **See the InnerException for details**

Comment: possible duplicate of [DbUpdateException with entities that do not expose foreign key properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113323/dbupdateexception-with-entities-that-do-not-expose-foreign-key-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did not configure the many-to-many relationship. In your DbContext paste something like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CONSUL_CA_Aluno>() 
           .HasMany(t => t.CONSUL_CA_Cursos) 
           .WithMany(t => t.CONSUL_CA_Alunos)

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Details on that are provided here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#ManyToMany

Comment: Also you'd need to specific the many to many cross reference table here, and define the key names inside of it.

Comment: @control - not really, only if he want to.